# How to delete a file, before I append new stuff into it in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I got a powershell script that loops through my input and creates an output

```
$output | Out-File -Filepath C:\Users\Soc.20150119_output.txt -append
```

Obviously it appends it to the file which already exists if you run it twice. I searched here, but I couldn't find a solution how to always write into a new file, each time the script runs.

Thanks for helping!

EDIT: I append content line by line. So a removal of -append is not the solution.

Comment: Just remove the `-append` switch

Comment: Thanks Micky. As it loops through my input I need it to append each line it processes to the file.

Comment: An ugly but fast way is `""| Out-File -Filepath C:\Users\Soc.20150119_output.txt` before the loop

Comment: Lets be ugly then. Thanks.

Comment: Better: fix the program logic that requires appending in a loop.

Comment: Possibly less ugly: Clear-Content  -Path C:\Users\Soc.20150119_output.txt

Comment: or you could add `remove-item C:\Users\Soc.20150119_output.txt` before the loop

Comment: @FrédéricBégin That would throw an error if the file doesn't exist, while MickyBalladelli's approach will add a spurious newline. mjolinor's approach is probably the least ugly one. Another option would be `$null > C:\Users\Soc.20150119_output.txt`.